# how to pass additional properties through Dagre?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, dagre

I'm using Dagre to layout my graph and need to send additional properties through to set class/style later in cytoscape.

```
var graph = new dagre.graphlib.Graph({...});

graph.setEdge(source, target, {
  val1: 'foo'
}, e.value);
```

How to access the additional property `val1` later when iterating through edges using `graph.edges()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you should probably be able to get it like that:

```
var edges = graph.edges();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
    // do stuff


    var data = edges[i].data().val1;  
    // or 
    var data = edges[i].data('val1');  
    // or get all attributes
    var data = edges[i].data();

    //do other stuff
}
```